# GIT - Determining # lines of code written per hour (committed & uncommitted)

Tags: git

I want to graph the # of new lines of code written each hour over the course of the day.

I'm aware of git diff, git log and they are very powerful for determining total # of lines committed to a branch. The --since="7am" option is really great as well.

Some of the git commands I'm utilizing are:

**Total # of lines**

```
git log --numstat --pretty="%H" master | awk 'NF==3 {plus+=$1; minus+=$2} END {printf("+%d, -%d\n", plus, minus)}'
```

**# lines additional in devel branch compared to master**

```
git log --numstat --pretty="%H" master..devel | awk 'NF==3 {plus+=$1; minus+=$2} END {printf("+%d, -%d\n", plus, minus)}'
```

**# lines since a time of day**

```
git log --since="7am" --format=format: --numstat | awk 'NF==3 {plus+=$1; minus+=$2} END {printf("%d, -%d\n", plus, minus)}'
```

**# lines currently uncommitted**

```
git diff --stat | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'
```

I've been struggling though with coming up with a way to track the # of new lines written in the past hour including uncommitted changes, across all branches in the current repo.

This may be more of a math problem.

## The Question:

- How can I determine the exact amount of lines written in the past hour across all branches, including uncommitted changes.

## Gotchas/Scenarios:

- +200 uncommitted at 7pm is 200 new lines written. +250 uncommitted at 8pm is only 50 new lines written the past hour.
- +200 uncommitted at 7pm is 200 new lines written. At 8pm we commit 100 of the lines and then write 50 more new lines. Now +150 show as uncommitted, but we would need to determine that only 50 new lines were written in the past hour. Reconciling committed and uncommitted stats.
- +200 uncommitted at 7pm. At 7:30pm we write 500 additional new lines and commit them. At 8pm we write 100 more new lines thus showing +300 as uncommitted. We should end up with 600 new lines written in the last hour.

Comment: Because of the Gotchas you mention, you're probably going to have to go with a solution that stores the last run's results (in a file, DB, in the repository with `git config`, etc.) and then compares this time's results against them.  The simplest of the storage options for keeping the last value is probably the `git config` one, but since you want to keep historical data to graph, you probably want a simple database anyway.  If you already have a running database server, you could use it, or you could use a file-based DB like SQLite.

Comment: Yep, got a MySQL database to store total lines of code ever added, and the # of lines COMMITTED in the past hour. I'm still a bit unsure how to approach assessing the uncommitted lines of code without double counting it.

Comment: Compare the uncommitted lines from this run with the total of uncommitted from last run and committed from this run.  The difference will be the number of new lines. For your first example: 250 + 0 - 200 = 50. For your second example: 150 + 100 - 200 = 50.  For your third, 300 + 500 - 200 = 600.

Comment: Who is to say that the number of lines in a commit at a certain time represent the when it was written? What if I stashed my changes and left them there for eons?

Comment: I hope some poor sods aren't going to get judged on their productivity by this measure -
`it\n` `could\n` `drive\n` `some\n` `serious\n` `degradation\n` `in\n` `code\n` `quality!\n` :)

Comment: Are you taking history rewriting into account? What about lines existing just in the editor, not stored in the working tree yet? This could be an issue e.g. when writing documentation comments.

Comment: I'm aware that lines of codes != measure of productivity. And the stashed is a scenario I didn't consider.

Comment: You should track the number of lines removed instead.

Comment: Why not number of bytes instead of lines of code? (I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish you could have a good reason I'm just curious)

Comment: put the code on github and have that statistic there allready :)

Comment: I agree with @JamesWorld.

Comment: @Lenny MaybeYouShouldTryReadingThisVariableName int;

Answer (score 2):

There's a tool [gitstats](https://github.com/hoxu/gitstats) that can give you `Lines of Code` by date.
Maybe you can tweak a little the code (is written in python) to let him generate hourly stats.